# Как рисовать 2D пользовательский интерфейс в игре поверх 3D?

Tags: java, opengl, разработка-игр, gui, lwjgl

Я создал 3D игру наподобие Minecraft на языке Java при помощи библиотеки LWJGL. Так же могу передвигаться по миру, смотреть вверх, вниз, оглядываться, и так далее. А как отобразить панель, наподобие той, которую я выделил красным цветом на прикреплённом рисунке?

[image: Minecraft Screenshot]

Допустим, эти квадратики я нарисовал в Paint'е и сохранил в файле `panel.png`, но как её отобразить?

Напишите примерный исходный код.

Comment: плохо разбираюсь в теме, но может нужен просто плейн который впритык к камере? на нем отрисовывать УЙ.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду GUI? Тогда, возможно это так. Я примерно соображаю, что нужно сделать, но не могу в интернете подобные вопросы найти. Я не знаю как другие разработчики это делают.

Comment: (уй\ui\gui) да, это имею ввиду :)
сам вижу это вот так: https://i.gyazo.com/331fcc41370eeb22a0412cb4a7eb913f.png но т.к не разрабатывал 3д, то это просто моё видение\предположение и как делают тоже не знаю. красный - это плейн на котором отрисовываем gui

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В коде инициализации экрана (перед главным циклом) написать следующий код:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
Texture i4 = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream("textures" + File.separator + "myTexture.png"));
```

А в главном цикле следующее:

```
while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    i4.bind();
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    // Координаты и разрешение текстуры
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0F, 0F);
    GL11.glVertex2f(100F, 100F);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1F, 0F);
    GL11.glVertex2f(100F + (float) i4.getTextureWidth(), 100F);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1F, 1F);
    GL11.glVertex2f(100F + (float) i4.getTextureWidth(), 100F + (float) i4.getTextureHeight());
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0F, 1F);
    GL11.glVertex2f(100F, 100F + (float) i4.getTextureHeight());
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

Comment: В вопросе написал всё, что требовалось сделать. Работает супер.

Answer (score 6):

Создайте отдельный контейнер для спрайтов, закреплённый относительно камеры и разместите в нём спрайты пользовательского интерфейса.
В качестве контейнера можно использовать поростой прямоугольник с текстурой (канвой). С текстурой (канвой) можно оперировать через PixelWriter и PixelReader, перерисовывая области на плоскости.

Либо можно сделать аналог Group из JavaFX, так же закрепить его экземпляр относительно камеры и уже добавлять 3D элементы интерфейса.

UPD: Посмотрите обсуждение здесь https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues/101

UPD2: Вот здесь вопрос уже обсуждался https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/making-a-hud-gui-with-opengl-lwjgl (Кратко: человек отрисовывает мир, а потом уже интерфейс поверх мира только и всего).

UPD3: И ещё одна рекомендация здесь https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/29284 - использовать готовую библиотеку для GUI в LWJGL - Nifty (http://void256.github.io/blog/ -> https://github.com/nifty-gui/nifty-gui)

Answer (score 4):

В общем подход такой:

1. Рисуем игру в объемной проекции (перспектива и т.п.)
2. Переключаем проекцию на ортографическую
3. Выключаем буфер глубины
4. Рисуем интерфейс

Comment: У меня основной вопрос заключался в том не что для этого необходимо, а как это сделать, то есть примерный исходный код. Мне и так ясно, что нужно глубину убрать и перейти из 3D режима в 2D. Как это сделать? Исходный код нужен.

Comment: @Lesperanza так укажите это в вопросе

Comment: Теперь указал. Так всё-таки вы знаете как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В андроиде есть `FrameLayout` для отображения одного контента поверх второго, думаю такая штука есть и в вашей отрасли